# MBProgresshud set it in landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mbprogresshud

i am implementing MBProgresshud in my app in AppDelegate file

```
-(void)showProgressHUD:(NSString*)msg{
if(mbProcess!=nil && [mbProcess retainCount]>0){ 
    [mbProcess removeFromSuperview];
    [mbProcess release];
    mbProcess=nil;
}
mbProcess=[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:self.window];
mbProcess.labelText=@"";
mbProcess.detailsLabelText = msg;
[self.window addSubview:mbProcess];
[mbProcess setDelegate:(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]];
[mbProcess show:YES];
}
```

i called in DidFinish launching

like `[self showProgressHUD:@"Loading..."];`

My app is in default Landscape method.

Now the issue is when the app start the progress hud first set into portrait and then in a second, it rotate in landscape.

I need this hud all time in landscape

thank you

Comment: That call to retainCount is complete nonsense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since MBProgressHud is a subclass of UIView, you can try to rotate manually your progressHud before show it ?

```
mbProcess.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
[self.window addSubview:mbProcess];
[mbProcess show:YES];
```

Careful angle should be in radian (so for a 90° rotation you should use something like M_PI/2 or (-M_PI/2))

Comment: No change. same result again.

Comment: finally get the solution. first I check the orientation then set the i load the MBProgressHud. Thank You

Comment: @Hiren can you explain better your solution?

Comment: Works for me. But as in landscape mode, need to put an angle of 2*M_PI.